# bootstrap grid - 3 columns and 2 rows into 2 columns and 3 rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

Hi I have typical bootstrap grid

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">A</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">B</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">C</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">D</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">E</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">F</div>
</div>
```

On a larger or medium screen it shows

```
A B C
D E F
```

On a very small screen it shows

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Ok now my question. Is this possible to make on very small screen to show last colum as last row

```
A B
D E
C F
```

Than you for help.

Comment: Not without heavily modifying Bootstrap 3s Grid structure to support Flexbox.  Bootstrap 4 would offer you the native ability to re-order your columns via the `.order-*-*` class, but they would need to all be in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another grid with the desired order for an extra small screen and show/hide the two grids using Bootstrap's responsive utilities.

For example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">C</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">D</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">E</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center" style="font-size:150px">F</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row visible-xs-block">
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="center" style="font-size:150px">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="center" style="font-size:150px">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="center" style="font-size:150px">D</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="center" style="font-size:150px">E</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="center" style="font-size:150px">C</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" align="center" style="font-size:150px">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```